# How to point SQL Server Python to a specific Python install?

Tags: sql-server, installation, python

SQL Server 2017 installs an instance of Python to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES" ([documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/concepts/extension-python?view=sql-server-2017)) that it uses for its Python calls. This is installed with specific packages that SQL Server needs to communicate with Python.

Is there documentation on these packages, where to pull them (pip?), and how to point SQL Server to a different install of Python on the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* point SQL Server to a different Python installation; per the docs you linked:

> SQL Server does not modify the Python executables, but you **must** use the version of Python installed by Setup because that version is the one that the proprietary packages are built and tested on. For a list of packages supported by the Anaconda distribution, see the Continuum analytics site: [Anaconda package list](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs).

The Python 3.5 runtime and interpreter are available from [this](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) site.